# Redirect if date <= current date

Tags: php, sql

I want to check the `date` in the database and redirect the user to another page if the `date` in the database is before todays date.

I currently have:

```
<?php
 $user_name = "root";
 $password = "";
 $database = "db";
 $server = "localhost";

 $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
 $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

 if ($db_found) {
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT `date` FROM users WHERE user_id='1'");
  $res = mysql_fetch_row($result);

  if ($res[0] == 1){
   header ("Location: ./error.php");
  }                        
  else
  {
   echo ' ';
  }
 }
 else
 {
  print "Database NOT Found.";
  mysql_close($db_handle);
 }
?>
```

How can I make this working?

Comment: `date` is a reserved word. To use it as a column name, put backticks ( ` ) around it. You should ideally do this for all column/table names.

Comment: Once you have that, just compare `$res[0] < date('Y-m-d');` and you should be set.

Comment: And then, secure your application. Connecting to the DB as `root` is a very bad idea. Also, you should not use `mysql_*` functions as they have been removed in current versions of PHP.

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol date is not reserved. If you check the online documentation there is no (R) next to its name.

Comment: I changed the name of date to something else, but the script is not working

Comment: Ok, its working. I forgot to close the sql query

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol `date` is a keyword, but it's not a reserved word. You don't need backticks around it. And code that puts backticks around everything is incredibly ugly, IMHO.

Comment: @Barmar PHP strings don't need quotes either (`$somevar = hello;`) but I'll wager you put them on, every time, and don't consider it ugly.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Not putting quotes there means it's a constant. PHP will convert a constant to a string if it's not defined, but it prints a warning when it does it -- it's not normal syntax.

Comment: @Barmar Likewise, not putting backticks means it's a keyword/reserved word. MySQL will convert it to a table/column name if it's not defined. Granted you get no warning, but to me it's the same deal.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol That's ridiculous. The backticks aren't even part of standard SQL syntax, they're a MySQL addition.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol The reason why it's uglier than quotes around strings is because there are so many identifiers in a SQL statement. You end up with backticks every few characters, and they get in the way of seeing the code structure.

Comment: It's the same reason why `"abc $foo def $bar ghi $baz"` is easier to read in PHP than `"abc " . $foo . " def " . $bar . " ghi " . $baz`

Comment: @Barmar Hmm, I would argue in favour of concatenation over interpolation as it communicates intent better, at least in my opinion. And that goes for backticks too. In my opinion, they make it very clear that "this is an identifier", which additionally helps for syntax highlighting.

Comment: I guess we'll have to agree to disagree. I use an IDE that highlights keywords, and I also like the style where keywords are uppercase while tables and columns are lowercase. Either way, backticks are superfluous. And I try to avoid using reserved words as names (it was annoying when another programmer here used `key` as a column name).

Answer (score 1):

The following will add that to your database query and only return a row if both are found...

```
$user_name = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "db";
$server = "localhost";

$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

if (!$db_found) {
    mysql_close($db_handle);
    print "Database NOT Found.";
    exit();
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE user_id='1' AND date < CURDATE()");
if ($res = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    //user matched and date is larger that current date
    mysql_close($db_handle);
    header ("Location: ./error.php");
    exit();
}                        

//user not matched or date is not larger that current date
//do something else
```